# Convert json to dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, json

I have a json array f below format

```
[{
    'Address': 'xxx',
    'Latitude': 28. xxx,
    'Longitude': 77. xxx,
    'reached': False
}, {
    'Address': 'yyy',
    'Latitude': 18. yyy,
    'Longitude': 73. yyy,
    'reached': False
}]
```

i want to convert into dataframe. if the column name is same it should have (Address_0, Address_1 etc) and should be side by side, not below. How can i do this?

Comment: Did you tried, what happens, what error shown?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `pandas.read_json` method? ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html))

And it looks like your json is structured like `'records'` so use

```
pd.read_json(_, orient='records')
```

Comment: im getting error **ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>**

Comment: Did you change the underscore to the actual path? `pd.read_json(PATH_HERE, orient='records')`

Comment: The error you are getting is caused by the fact that the variable you are inputting (i.e.  your data) is of type list, not a json string.

Comment: i have already read the input and parsed it. the above records are inside **transit**.. so what I have done is **eachData['transits']=transitArray**.. so above records are in transitarray.. so what should I do next?

Comment: Where are you getting your input data from and how are you parsing it? The issue is coming from the fact that your data is a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pd.DataFrame.from_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) method like:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `pd.json_normalize(data)`. It normalizes json structure into flat table of data:

```
data = [{
'Address': 'xxx',
'Latitude': 28.000,
'Longitude': 77.000,
'reached': False}, {
'Address': 'yyy',
'Latitude': 18.000,
'Longitude': 73.000,
'reached': False}]
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

[image]